# Does FuncAnimation allow any kind of sleep() function without blocking the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, measurement

I'm writing a code for controlling multiple devices which communicate by Serial with Python, some of them take measurements and others control the conditions of those. I want to graph the data collected in real time, so I've used FuncAnimation from matplotlib for this purpose. My animate function has this structure:

```
def animate(i, data1, data2, device1, device2):
    device1.set_condition()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    device2.measure()
```

The device 1 sets a value in my system (Magnetic field, voltage, light, etc), then I must wait a small time interval for the stabilization of my system, so I've used time.sleep() for this, but the plot from FuncAnimation gets blocked for 0.2 s for every iteration because of this. Is there anyway to make FuncAnimation wait for this stabilization without getting blocked? Or is there any better way for achieving this?

Comment: if you really have to wait then you will have to run animation in separated thread

Comment: I don't have too much experience with threading. Would I take the measurements with a function in a thread and then pass the values to the animation in another thread? Anything more specific than that?

Comment: you use `sleep` inside `animate` so you have to run `animate` inside separated `thread`. OR rather you would have to run `FuncAnimation()` in separated thread  and it will run `animate` in this new thread.

Comment: I don't know what GUI you use to run it but some of them may have function to force GUI to updated widgets - and code will not block so much. For example in `tkinter` you can  `root.update()` for this. And then you can use `for _ in range(10): time.sleep(0.02) root.update()` to still sleep 0.2 (10*0.02) and run `update()` every `0.02s`

Comment: BTW: I never used this but `matplot` has [pause](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pause.html) - and maybe it will be better than `sleep`

Comment: OR maybe you should run it in different way: before animation run `device.set_condition()`  and later start animation with `interval=200`(ms) - and animation should first display `device2.measure()` (for values generated before animation) and at once run `device1.set_condition()` to generate data for next frame which will be executed after `interval=200`

Comment: @furas That last one sounds like a great solution. I think it will work for me in this case because I have only one device which changes its conditions dynamically. I guess it would also work if I have several devices but the time between each one of them doesn't matter, but it would be more complicated in the other case. Thank you, I will try this solution later!